# Why Spark DataFrame Repartition not working correctly

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hortonworks-data-platform

Spark 1.6.2 HDP 2.5.2

I am using spark sql to fetch data from a hive table and then **repartitioning on a particular column "serial" with 100 partitions but spark does not repartition the data into 100 partitions (can be seen as number of tasks in spark ui) instead has 126 tasks.**

```
val data = sqlContext.sql("""select * from default.tbl_orc_zlib""")
val filteredData = data.filter( data("day").isNotNull ) // NULL check

//Repartition on serial column with 100 partitions
val repartData = filteredData.repartition(100,filteredData("serial")) 
val repartSortData = repartData.sortWithinPartitions("serial","linenr")

val mappedData = repartSortData.map(s => s.mkString("\t"))
val res = mappedData.pipe("xyz.dll")
res.saveAsTextFile("hdfs:///../../../")
```

But if i use a coalesce first and then repartition then the number of tasks become 150 (correct 50 of coalesce and 100 of repartition)

```
filteredData.coalesce(50)//works fine
```

Can someone please explain me why is this happening

Comment: Please attach a screen shot of the Spark UI.

Comment: Please provide the DAG scheduler after applying both coalesce and repartition. To get the DAG scheduler, use `repartSortData .rdd.toDebugString`